# Stuck! Need to create a class with a method then create 4 properties

Tags: javascript

Come up with the error:

Failed tests

Should contain properties: email, username, password, and checkPassword
Expected undefined to be 'Frank'.

Watched a couple of videos looked it up on W3Schools and MDN and nothing is clicking. Input appreciated.

```
    function ClassTwo(name, pw, mail){
  // Exercise Two: Now that you have created your own class, 
  // you will create a class with a method on it.
  // In this class create 4 properties: username, password, email, and checkPassword.
  // Set the value of username to name,
  // Set the value of password to pw,
  // Set the value of email to mail
  // Set the value of checkPassword to a function. 
  // The checkPassword function takes a string as it's only argument.
  // Using the 'this' keyword check to see if the password on the class is the same as 
  // the string being passed in as the parameter. Return true or false.
}
function User (username, password, email, checkPassword) {

  this.username = name;                           // My Code
  this.password = pw;                             // My Code
  this.email = mail;                              // My Code
  this.checkPassword = checkPass;             // My Code
  this.checkPassword = function(abc123){         // My Code
    return this.checkPassword;                   // My Code 
  }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough of your code here to be able to answer this question, unfortunately. How are you calling `checkPassword`? And how does `abc123` tie into things? Also, `its` should not have an apostrophe in that comment.

Comment: I didn't make the comments except for my code it is an assignment. As far as the code goes that is all there is. The abc123 is the string (password) being passed to check and see if the passwords are the same.

Comment: Your checkPassword method is overwriting your checkPassword property as they both are called the same.

Comment: @James I changed it and still have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the right argument names when assigning property values in the User function. Also, 'checkPassword' doesn't have to be passed as the 4th argument. It should be:

```
function User (username, password, email) {

  this.username = username;
  this.password = password;
  this.email = email;
  this.checkPassword = function(string) {
    return this.password == string;
  }

}
```

This way we're passing the same number of arguments to the function (like in 'function ClassTwo(name, pw, mail)'.

Alternatively, following the prototype approach, you can create a method:

```
User.prototype.checkPassword = function(string) {
  return this.password == string; 
}
```

It will return true if the argument string is the same as the declared password and false otherwise.

Also, the more modern way of doing the above would be:

```
class User {
  constructor(username, password, email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
  }
  checkPassword(string) {
    return this.password == string; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I modified the answer so it would follow the instructions. Please check if the first fragment of code will do it for you.

Comment: The top answer worked. You Rock. Thank you very much!

Comment: It didn't work with class User for some reason it workrd with 
function ClassTwo (username, password, email)